# $\tan A=n\tan B$, then find the maximum value of $(\tan(A-B))^2$

Tags: trigonometry

If $\tan A=n\tan B$, then find the maximum value of $(tan(A-B))^2$.

What I did was wrote $n-1=(\tan A-\tan B)/\tan B$. But I don't know how to write $1+\tan A\tan B$ in terms of n and when maximum will occur. The answer is $(n-1)(n-1)/4n$.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please use MathJax.
For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Answer (score 1):

Put $\tan A=n\tan B$ into $\displaystyle \tan(A-B)=\frac{\tan A-\tan B}{1+\tan A\tan B}$

$$\tan(A-B)=\frac{(n-1)\tan B}{1+n\tan^2 B}=\frac{n-1}{n\tan B+\cot B}$$

$$\tan^2(A-B)=\frac{(n-1)^2}{(n\tan B+\cot B)^2}$$

$$\tan^2(A-B)=\frac{(n-1)^2}{(n\tan B-\cot B)^2+4n\tan B\cot B}$$

for maximum of $\tan^2(A-B),$ Quantity $(n\tan B-\cot B)^2$ is minimum

which is $=0$ (i e $(n\tan B-\cot B)^2\geq 0$)

$$\Longrightarrow \tan^2(A-B)_{\max}=\frac{(n-1)^2}{4n}$$

Comment: because $4n\tan B\cot B=4n.$ (assuming that $n$ is constant)

Answer (score 1):

Let $t:=\tan B$ so, if $n>0$,$$\tan(A-B)=\frac{\tan A-\tan B}{1+\tan A\tan B}=\frac{(n-1)t}{1+nt^2}\implies|\tan(A-B)|=\left|\frac{n-1}{\sqrt{n}}\right|\left.\frac{|u|}{1+u^2}\right|_{u=t\sqrt{n}}.$$Applying AM-GM to the function of $u$, this has upper bound $\left|\frac{n-1}{2\sqrt{n}}\right|$, so $\tan^2(A-B)\le\frac{(n-1)^2}{4n}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y=\tan(A-B)=\dfrac{t(n-1)}{1+nt^2}$ where $t=\tan B$

$$\implies ynt^2-t(n-1)+y=0$$

As $t$ is real, the discriminant must be $\ge0$

$$(n-1)^2\ge4ny^2$$

which is a tautology if $n\le0,$ so $y$ can assume any real value

For $n>0,$ $$y^2\le\dfrac{(n-1)^2}{4n}$$